# How to Unpivot datatable in DAX Studio?

Tags: powerbi, dax, data-manipulation, powerbi-desktop, daxstudio

I have a `datatable` as below and I would like to unpivot it in DAX studio. New `MonthFY` column should consist of the date values. Many thanks in advance.

```
    EVALUATE
Var mydf =
DATATABLE (
    "Group A", STRING, "Variable", STRING,
    "Apr FY23", CURRENCY, "May FY24", CURRENCY,
    "Jun FY24", CURRENCY,"Jul FY24", CURRENCY,

    {
    
        { "Gorup A", "Additions_at_Cost", 10000, 20000 ,50000,60000},
        { "Group A", "Accum_Dep", 5000, 6000, 75000,8500},
        { "Group A", "Accum_Dep Dispositions Impairments",10 ,10,1000, 1000},
        { "Group A", "Dispositions", 999,999, 5000,5000},
        
        { "Gorup B", "Additions_at_Cost", 10000, 20000 ,50000,60000},
        { "Group B", "Accum_Dep", 5000, 6000, 75000,8500},
        { "Group B", "Accum_Dep Dispositions Impairments", 10,10,1000, 1000},
        { "Group B", "Dispositions", 999,999, 5000,5000}
    }
)
Return mydf
```

What I did is;

```
EVALUATE
VAR t1 = SELECTCOLUMNS ( 'mydf',   "Group A", {"Group A", "Group B"}, 
"Variable", {"Additions_at_Cost","Accum_Dep","Accum_Dep Dispositions Impairments","Dispositions"},   
"MonthFY", "Apr FY23","Value", [Apr FY23] )

VAR t2 = SELECTCOLUMNS ( 'mydf',   "Group A", {"Group A", "Group B"}, 
"Variable", {"Additions_at_Cost","Accum_Dep","Accum_Dep Dispositions Impairments","Dispositions"},    
"MonthFY", "May FY24","Value", [May FY24] )

VAR t3 = SELECTCOLUMNS ( 'mydf',   "Group A", {"Group A", "Group B"}, 
"Variable", {"Additions_at_Cost","Accum_Dep","Accum_Dep Dispositions Impairments","Dispositions"},   
"MonthFY", "Jun FY24","Value", [Jun FY24] )

VAR t4 = SELECTCOLUMNS ( 'mydf',   "Group A", {"Group A", "Group B"}, 
"Variable", {"Additions_at_Cost","Accum_Dep","Accum_Dep Dispositions Impairments","Dispositions"},   
"MonthFY", "July FY24","Value",[July FY24] )

RETURN UNION ( t1, t2, t3, t4 )
```

Comment: Unpivoting in DAX is not really advised. Will you accept a Power Query solution?

Comment: What exactly should your resulting table look like?

Comment: Yeah, it should be a table with 3 columns;
 Group A, Variable, and MonthFY

Comment: wide dataset --> long dataset

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Table 2 = 
UNION(
    SELECTCOLUMNS('Table', "Group A", 'Table'[Group A],"Variable", 'Table'[Variable], "Attribute", "AprFY23", "Value", 'Table'[Apr FY23]),
    SELECTCOLUMNS('Table', "Group A", 'Table'[Group A],"Variable", 'Table'[Variable], "Attribute", "MayFY24", "Value", 'Table'[May FY24]),
    SELECTCOLUMNS('Table', "Group A", 'Table'[Group A],"Variable", 'Table'[Variable], "Attribute", "JunFY24", "Value", 'Table'[Jun FY24]),
    SELECTCOLUMNS('Table', "Group A", 'Table'[Group A],"Variable", 'Table'[Variable], "Attribute", "JulFY24", "Value", 'Table'[Jul FY24])
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As Davide said, I'd do this in PowerQuery unless you need the data in the original format for some reason.

You just go into the PowerQuery editor, select the first two columns, and then select Unpivot Other Columns, and you should be set.